# how to broadcast when out of socket.io loop

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have following code on server side, which does function call on new connection with socket.

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.broadcast.emit('user connected');
});
```

now i have another module that takes rest request and it want to broadcast on all open sockets. How can it be done?

Is there any way to use broadcast without socket? like

```
io.broadcast.emit('user connected');
```

**Edit** 
more like this?

```
io.sockets.broadcast.to('m1').emit('user message', 'from', 'msg');
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, indeed! Just call it on io.sockets.

```
io.sockets.emit('user connected')
```

This is pretty much exactly what `broadcast` does, except that `broadcast` takes the extra step of excluding itself from the broadcast.

Edit:

To scope to the room, like you've specified, do this:

```
io.sockets.in('m1').emit('user message', 'from', 'msg');
```

Comment: I am trying to use broadcast.to('m1') which will need broadcast, is there any way to access broadcast?

Comment: Updated post to match. "broadcast" itself simply sets flags on the current socket, so there is no global "broadcast" object to access; you have to use the methods that exist on the namespace.